# Is a "local memory program" the same thing as a "serial program"?

Tags: serialization, parallel-processing

Would something like this, that does not implement pthreads, MPI, openMP, etc. be considered a local memory program?

```
int main() {
    int arr[] = { 10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    
    quickSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
    printf("Sorted quicksort: \n");
    printArray(arr, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Local memory program" doesn't seem to be standard terminology.  Can you link to the source where you saw it used, and if possible the definition that they give?

Comment: Ok, I see. I thought it was standard terminology. I saw it in a parallel programming class I'm taking. I need to write both a local memory and shared memory version of a program. I'm guessing shared memory is the parallel implementation and local memory is the serial implementation.

Comment: In this context, a "local memory program" should be a program that work on variables stored in the local process/thread (ie. locally). With MPI, this means that each process work on local variables and exchange data using collectives. MPI also provide a way to share memory between processes. OpenMP is a standard for shared-memory parallel programming and so a "local memory program" does not make much sense in that case.

Comment: My guess (interpretation) is that using reduction is the "local memory" version, while using atomic operation(s) is the shared memory version. So, both versions are parallel, but the data race is handled differently.